# Adding a GeForce GPU will add up the graphics processing on Gigabyte 880GM?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, gpu

My Motherboard - [Gigabyte GA-880GM-USB3](http://www.gigabyte.in/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3412).
It has onboard graphics ATI Radeon HD 4250.

I have a spare GPU - GeForce 8400GS 512MB DDR2 and I was wondering if I shall add it to my system.
The only reason I'd add is when both the cards are processing the graphics. So will it happen?

I am aware that my motherboard has some technology named CrossFireX for using multiple GPUs, but will GeForce's work here?

Comment: No;  `Crossfire` is not compatible with `Nvidia` products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they won’t. These features are vendor-locked, for course.

I (personally) think the performance gain (over just having a dedicated graphics card) is rather questionable. I don’t have any benchmarks handy, though. Having a single graphics card still provides the least problems and best compatibility.

Comment: I can tell you that mixing a built in and GPU and dedecated Nvidia GPU would result in an either situation they won't combine like the author believe

Comment: Both NVIDIA and ATI offer solutions for achieving what the OP wants: Hybrid SLI (semi-discontinued) and Hybrid Graphics (apparently, “Dual Graphics”, now), respectively. Naturally, different vendors don’t combine.